# AngularJS intercepting http not through $http provider

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have an AngularJS application on Azure App Services secured by Active Directory, and am trying to create a connection via websocket using socket.io.

The problem is AD will cause a 302 redirect response which socket.io does not follow, so I would like to intercept the response and follow it after which socket.io connections should be fine.   However, the socket.io calls are not via the $http provider and therefore cannot be managed with a typical interceptor.

Is there anyway to pick these up with an interceptor or perhaps middleware?   I haven't had any luck trying typical middleware solutions (e.g. app.use(...)).

Note that socket.io will work with polling but that would likely cause performance issues with my application.

Using the following interceptor, I get no outputs to the console log even though I can see the calls and 302 responses in Fiddler:

```
app.factory('httpInterceptor', [function() {  
    var httpInterceptor = {
         request: function(req) {

            if (req.url.indexOf('socket.io') > -1) {
              console.log('REQUEST');
              console.log(req);              
            }
            return req;
         },

         requestError: function(reqerr) {
           console.log(reqerr);            
         },

         response: function(res) {   
            if ( res.status == 302 ) {
              console.log('RESPONSE');
              console.log(res); 
            }
            return res;
         },

         responseError: function(reserr) {      
           console.log(reserr);
         }
    };
    return httpInterceptor;
}]);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
}]);
```

Comment: 302 redirects are handled by the browser and are not received by the XHR API.

Comment: I see. If I copy the Location header contents from the 302 into the browser I get the output from the socket.io server.   After that the socket will connect in the app and it works fine (I assume because AD now considers the session authenticated).   It seems however that socket.io is not happy with what it is getting back after the redirection:
Refused to execute script from 'https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/socket.io/ws/iothub/?EIO=3&transport=polling&j=0&t=MHUQKJY&b64=1' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.